# RequestMapping returns 404 error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, request-mapping

Yep, I know - there are tones of such questions. I tryed to scan all of them, but the didn't help me.
Here is my code:

**dispatcher servlet**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

**web.xml**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Controller**:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView hello() {
    return new ModelAndView("index");
   }
}
```

**Files location**

HomeController is located in com.package.controller package.

index.jsp is located in WEB-INF/jsp/ package.

URL I'm trying to access is: localhost:8080/hello.do

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for help!

Comment: what is the exact name of your dispatcher servlet xml file?

Comment: MDaniyal, Sorry, skiped your question. File name is *dispatcher-servlet.xml*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run your project the code is working fine, Can you follow the below project structure?

[image]

Comment: Tried to give @RequestMapping("*") on HomeController.

localhost:8080/hello.do is still invalid.  
Thanks for help, anyway :)

Comment: <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> didn't help either

Comment: is the name of your dispatcher file is `dispatcher-servlet.xml` ?

Comment: ok then try `value = "hello"` instead of `value = "/hello"` on your method with `@RequestMapping("*")` on your class

Comment: Ok, now I have `@RequestMapping("*")` on my controller class,
`@RequestMapping(value = "hello")` on my hello method, and (didn't change it) dispatcher, looking for **.do* pattern.
But URL http://localhost:8080/hello.do is still invalid.

Comment: Your code is working like a charm the only difference in my case is the bean defination: <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

Comment: Thats really strange. Maybe some bug in Idea?  What IDE are you using?

Comment: No this is not possible, I am using IntelliJ Idea 14.1.4

Comment: Can you send your project to me?

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot for your help. Here is a link: https://github.com/IvanNikolaychuk/tmp

Comment: I have edited the answer kindly check now @ИванНиколайчук

Comment: thats really strange. I followed this structure and it still doesn't work. I recorded a video, showing all my steps, they look valid for me. Can you please take a look at it? Here is a link: https://yadi.sk/i/FPqqwvYLqq7WM (you'd better download it before watchin - the quality will be good then)

Comment: Hey, I got it!
The problem is: in my Intellij configs, servlet-dipatcher was mapped as "Spring Application context" first, and only then as "MVC dispatcher servlet". Seems like this file was treeted as "App context" only. 
When I swaped this order, everything went fine. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sorry I didn't get time to see your video. That I was thinking but forget to told you that you can check this by going to `View --> Tool Windows --> Spring` there you can check all Beans and MVC components.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is not correct. Try with localhost:8080/"yourapplicationName"/hello.do. For example in my case if my application war file is abc.war then the url would be localhost:8080/abc/hello.do

Comment: No, the code is working fine issue is might be with project structure. with this URL `http://localhost:9090/hello.do`